# React Native Creating project

Tags: react-native

Description
i am beginner in react native and facing issue while creating new project with react native cli

React Native Version
React Native 0.72.3,

Output of npx react-native info

```
### Steps to reproduce

at ios directory of project ios % bundle exec pod install

### Snack, code example, screenshot, or link to a repository

jamalahamad@Jamals-MacBook-Pro ios % bundle exec pod install
Framework build type is static library
[Codegen] Generating ./build/generated/ios/React-Codegen.podspec.json
....
[Hermes] Using the release tarball from Maven Central
Downloading dependencies
Installing CocoaAsyncSocket (7.6.5)
 React-Core (0.72.0)
...
Installing glog (0.3.5)
[!] /bin/bash -c 
set -e
#!/bin/bash
# Copyright (c) Meta Platforms, Inc. and affiliates.
#
# This source code is licensed under the MIT license found in the
# LICENSE file in the root directory of this source tree.

set -e

PLATFORM_NAME="${PLATFORM_NAME:-iphoneos}"
CURRENT_ARCH="${CURRENT_ARCH}"

if [ -z "$CURRENT_ARCH" ] || [ "$CURRENT_ARCH" == "undefined_arch" ]; then
    # Xcode 10 beta sets CURRENT_ARCH to "undefined_arch", this leads to incorrect linker arg.
    # it's better to rely on platform name as fallback because architecture differs between simulator and device

    if [[ "$PLATFORM_NAME" == *"simulator"* ]]; then
        CURRENT_ARCH="x86_64"
    else
        CURRENT_ARCH="arm64"
    fi
fi



# Manually disable gflags include to fix issue https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/28446
sed -i.bak -e 's/\@ac_cv_have_libgflags\@/0/' src/glog/logging.h.in && rm src/glog/logging.h.in.bak
sed -i.bak -e 's/HAVE_LIB_GFLAGS/HAVE_LIB_GFLAGS_DISABLED/' src/config.h.in && rm src/config.h.in.bak

./configure --host arm-apple-darwin

cat << EOF >> src/config.h
/* Add in so we have Apple Target Conditionals */
#ifdef __APPLE__
#include <TargetConditionals.h>
#include <Availability.h>
#endif

/* Special configuration for ucontext */
#undef HAVE_UCONTEXT_H
#undef PC_FROM_UCONTEXT
#if defined(__x86_64__)
#define PC_FROM_UCONTEXT uc_mcontext->__ss.__rip
#elif defined(__i386__)
#define PC_FROM_UCONTEXT uc_mcontext->__ss.__eip
#endif
EOF
...

patching file config.sub
1 out of 1 hunks failed--saving rejects to config.sub.rej
```

I tried to reinstall cocoapods and set xcode Comman Line Tools,but it still not work

how can I resolve this problem